# Rails collection_select default select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, selected, collection-select

In Rails 4 in view I have

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: "Select your country" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I'd like "Select your country" to be selected as default whenever the page is loaded. One way is to use javascript (select it after the dom is loaded). Is there an easier way like adding an option to `collection_select`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

As per [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), it's the `prompt` option in the `options` argument:

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.find(:all),
                  :id, :name_with_initial,
                 {:prompt => 'Please select the author of this post'})
```

With `collection_select` on a form builder we omit the first argument, so in this case:

```
f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt: 'Select your country'}
```

I've 100% confirmed this as working on my own app running Rails 4.1.6, where `prompt` and `include_blank` do the same thing.

The way this works is Rails injects a null-valued `<option>` as the first item in the generated `<select>` (this is because the HTML spec has nothing analogous to `placeholder` on text inputs for select inputs).

Reasons this may fail:

1. Rails does not mark the prompt option with the `selected` attribute, and I suspect some browsers may choose to render their own blank entry instead of the first in the list
2. If, for existing records, Rails determines that the current record's `country_id` matches an element in the list it will mark that one as `selected`.  This is expected behaviour but can be a pain if you're doing anything non-standard.

If you're being bitten by these problems your options are to build the form manually (the method `options_from_collection_for_select` may be of use here) or do it in javascript.  There is also an undocumented `default` attribute you can add to an `<option>` tag but it's not in the spec and browser support may be patchy, and you'd still have to build the form manually.

Comment: Thanks for Googling for me but as per your very first answer, it doesn't work (Obviously I had done my Googling and there is also `include_blank: "..."`, but whenever you refresh the page, the option that was selected last before refresh is selected).

Comment: @user2725109 Try by writing like this: `<%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, {include_blank: "Select your country"} %>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Tried your format (placing `include_blank: "Select your country"` inside {}), but it didn't fix the problem, after refresh the last option before refresh is selected.

Comment: @user2725109: is it not displaying in the select box when the page loaded

Comment: @SLD. Thanks very much for your response. I tried it but it doesn't work. `include_blank: 'Prompt text'` only works as `options` but not `html_options`. Tried all different variations but no success.

Comment: My previous answer was confusing, and a third edit section would be tiresome and serve only to confuse any other readers, so I've edited one last time with (finally!) the right information.  I shouldn't have bothered answering in the first place really.  I hope it helps this time.

Comment: Also, @user2725109, I've been thinking about your comment above about the last option being selected on page refresh.  If the record has been saved, this is expected behaviour, but if it's a new record that hasn't been saved and you're still seeing this behaviour I would go into `application.js` and remove turbolinks, which in my experience causes nothing but trouble.